# Replacing GCMBaseIntentService with GoogleCloudMessaging

Tags: android, push-notification

I am new to Android development and I had to switch my first project from Eclipse to Android Studio finding library GCMBaseIntentService to be no longer supported. I found GoogleCloudMessaging, but it is not at all evident how to port the implementation I got from tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ here also listed, to that.
May someone help?

This is the piece of code I need to replace:

```
package com.example.taxiprofessional;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

import static com.example.taxiprofessional.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import static com.example.taxiprofessional.CommonUtilities.displayMessage;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

 public GCMIntentService() {
     super(SENDER_ID);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on device registered
  **/
 @Override
 protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
     displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
     AccountInformation info=AccountInformation.sharedInstance();
     ServerUtilities.register(context, info.email, info.password, registrationId);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on device un registred
  * */
 @Override
 protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
     displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
     ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on Receiving a new message
  * */
 @Override
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
     String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

     displayMessage(context, message);
     // notifies user
     generateNotification(context, message);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on receiving a deleted message
  * */
 @Override
 protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
     String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
     displayMessage(context, message);
     // notifies user
     generateNotification(context, message);
 }

 /**
  * Method called on Error
  * */
 @Override
 public void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
     displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
 }

 @Override
 protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
     // log message
     Log.i(TAG, "Received recoverable error: " + errorId);
     displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_recoverable_error,
             errorId));
     return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
 }

 /**
  * Issues a notification to inform the user that server has sent a message.
  */
 private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {
     int icon = R.drawable.taxi_profi;
     long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
     NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
             context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
     Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

     String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

     Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, Dashboard.class);
     // set intent so it does not start a new activity
     notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
     PendingIntent intent =
             PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
     notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
     notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

     // Play default notification sound
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

     // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
     notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
     notificationManager.notify(0, notification);      

 }

}
```

Thanks, Fabrizio

Comment: I used tutorial at: http://javapapers.com/android/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications/ and managed to compile, register and successfully deliver the notifications from the php server, yet nothing seems to arrive. I think the solution envisions GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver as the receiving part. It is fine or something else in addition to the manifest must be configured?

Comment: As a matter of fact the code is the same as that from google at: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: In particular the notification seems to arrive and mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build()); be called, but no notification appears on the device.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this, because I also just moved from eclipse to android studio

Comment: In which version the API is depreciated?

Comment: When porting the app to Android Studio.