# Error:(28, 34) error: package android.support.annotation does not exist

Tags: android, android-studio, dependencies, android-support-library, eclipse-adt

After importing an Eclipse ADT project into Android Studio, I'm seeing these errors:

`Error:(28, 34) error: package android.support.annotation does not exist`

`Error:(34, 34) error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist`

`Error:(26, 30) error: package android.support.v4.app does not exist`

I have installed the Android Support Library and Repository through SDK Manager, and here's my dependencies in the build.grade file for the module:

```
compile project(':pullToRefreshListView')
compile project(':facebook')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
```

Not sure why it doesn't see the Android support library.

Comment: try to clean Project , Rebuilt project and try

Comment: Did a clean and rebuild, still seeing the same error

Comment: @Ehsan Did you tried the fix of question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833606/android-support-library-error-after-updating-to-23-3-0? It is not the same issue but may help you

Comment: Solution (Gradle) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16690914/importing-notnull-or-nullable-and-android-studio-wont-compile

Answer (score 5):

My result is not so qualified but it works for my project.

When i look an old project, i had that problem at facebook module which was added in my project. *(That problem is not about facebook.)*

There is a jar file called **android-support-annotations.jar**.

This jar file is in **sdk_direction/extras/android/support/annotations/** path.

As first, I took it and i added it in that module's libs folder under my project.

Then i added below line in that module's `build.gradle` file;

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
```

As last, i synced the project and that problem has been resolved.

*useful ref* : [Missing annotations.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061986/missing-annotations-jar)

This error also can occur while porting or accidental removal of dependencies: [reference link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813974/error-while-porting-app-from-eclipse-to-android-studio/39239954)